# Getting all records (lat, Log) that contain polygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, select

I have a polygon and I want to get all the points inside from a georeference table.

What is the SQL for that?

For example, obtain all the lat/long records that are inside the department ZZ polygon.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the table names, and what do the geometry values look like? Please **edit** the question to clarify.  You'll also want the polygon to contain points, or have points contained by a polygon.

Comment: It would be easier to load the data into qgis and do a spatial query.

Answer (score 2):

Much easier if you post your table structure and what you've tried so far, but here goes.

Assuming you have a table points with a column point of type geometry, and a table polygons with a column polygon of type geometry:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
points p
INNER JOIN
polygons y
ON ST_CONTAINS(y.geometry, p.geometry)
WHERE y.department = 'ZZ'
```

If your points don't have geometry, but lon / lat columns, you can do `ST_POINT(lon,lat)` to convert them to geometry.